# Notebook is printing ' \n \tat' as it if as part of the string

Tags: string, jupyter-notebook, newline

I am doing a query on database, using a Python notebook, and retrieving a string. After retrieving I print this string, like print(string) and I have something like

```
"blabla\n \tat blabla\n \tat".
```

As you can see my notebook is not printing the new lines as it should, it shows '\n' as part of the string along with this '\tat'.

What can I try next? I think is related with this '\tat' but I could not find a lot about it (I imagine it maybe means EOL?)

Comment: `\t` is a tab character. I don't think `\tat` has a special meaning (except `    at` ).

Comment: hmm i see. But how can I avoid them to be printed as "\n\tat" and really do the new line and the tab then?

Comment: could be caused by a lot of things. personally, my first step would be to check the database, whether the string is actually correctly stored. Perhaps it is stored as literal characters '\', 'n' and 't'.

Comment: I think I found it! Following your tip I saw the database is correct, so this is okay. Moreover I do a "split" on \n before returning and this split keeps the \n, as I want, but when I print it does not recognize \n as a new line. Trying to figure this out... about the \t it's actually appending the word "at" that always exists after the \t, thanks for the tip, it helped me to find the issue on this :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer on the comments I understood that `\t` is a tab. In my case the world 'at' was always after, what leads to `\tat`.

Then, to solve this is possible to split by `'\t'` keeping the `\n` and print as:

```
print(*myListOfStrings, sep='\n')
```